# Limit rotated TextBlock size

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, xaml

I am trying to limit the first column height to match the second one's after rotating the TextBlock.

I have the following XAML:

```
<Viewbox>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <TextBlock
            Grid.Column='1'
            Text='Ubuntu'
            FontFamily='Ubuntu'
            FontSize='36' />

        <TextBlock
            Grid.Column='0'
            Text='Linux'
            FontFamily='Ubuntu'
            FontSize='36'>
            <TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
                <RotateTransform
                    Angle='-90' />
            </TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
        </TextBlock>

    </Grid>
</Viewbox>
```

Which will render the following:

[image: Actual output]

However, I'm trying to get this output, so that the height of the left column will adapt to that of the second:

[image: Desired output]

Have you got any idea how to do that purely with declarative XAML? Ie. no binding to heights or code-behind. I also do not want to specify any margins of the controls.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the best i could come up with. The bad part is the hardcoded row definition, but because you already have the root grid inside a viewbox, its relative, so it shouldn't be a big problem.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="36"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock
        Grid.Column='1'
        Text='Ubuntu'
        FontFamily='Ubuntu'
        FontSize='36' />

    <Viewbox Grid.Column='0'>
        <TextBlock
            Text='Linux'
            FontFamily='Ubuntu'
            FontSize='36'>
            <TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
                <RotateTransform
                    Angle='-90' />
            </TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
        </TextBlock>
    </Viewbox>
</Grid>
```

Comment: I don't really agree with hardcoding a height/width here :( Let me try to post my solution

Comment: Like i said, because it is in a viewbox, and we are dealing with vector graphics here, i don't see a problem with that. And the OP asked specifically for a solution without "binding to heights". Otherwise your solution is also perfectly valid. Now it depends what the OP actually needs.

Comment: Well since this would be incorporated into a larger scenario, I can not use bindings because of complexity and possible speed overhead (plus a lot of references and a mess in element names when auto-generating elements in the future if decided).And yes, the row height is a mess, but I haven't seen a better solution so I decided to pick this implementation up.
But thanks anyways for both of these solutions, I'm sure there are lots of people who'd appreciate either the binding or this hardcoded version.

Answer (score 2):

Slight modifications in your code can give you what you want:

**First: your updated code**

```
<Grid >
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <TextBlock x:Name="UbuntuBox"
            Grid.Column='1'
            Text='Ubuntu'
            FontFamily='Ubuntu'
            FontSize='36' />

            <TextBlock Width="{Binding ElementName=UbuntuBox, Path=Height}"
            Grid.Column='0'
            Text='Linux'
            FontFamily='Ubuntu'
            >
            <TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
                <RotateTransform
                    Angle='-90' />
            </TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
            </TextBlock>

        </Grid>
```

**Second: Explanations**

- Your `TextBlock` displaying "Linux" has to be linked to the Ubuntu `TextBlock` . In this case, its `Width` must be the same as Ubuntu's `Height`, so I added the following: `Width="{Binding ElementName=UbuntuBox, Path=Height}"`
- You can't have a `TextBlock` with a 36 `FontSize` fitting this given width. Removing it will keep it to default, then you can play with it if you want

And that's all you need! No hardcoded added stuff there =)